# <h1> </h1> attributes inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I have this html as follow, How to inheritate h1 style css inside javascript function myFunction. After click it picks default h1 style. Thanks.

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

 body {
    color: purple;
    font: normal 18px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: white }

 h1 {
    color: Red;
    font: normal 20px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: white }

</style>

<body>

<p id="demo"><h1>Click here.</h1></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Check it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
    document.writeln("<h1>", "Hello there", "</h1>");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<h1>` is not an attribute

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` (and `writeln`) will, if called when the document is in a *closed* state (which it will be after the DOM is ready) first call `document.open` and then *overwrite* the document.

Since the document is overwritten, the stylesheet is destroyed.

So the solution is **don't use `document.writeln`**. Use standard DOM methods instead. If you need an introduction on how to do that, then the W3C host a [web standards curriculum](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) which includes chapters on Traversing the DOM and Creating and modifying HTML.

Comment: Thanks. How to get css style inside function using standard DOM methods ?

Comment: Your question suggested that you just want the CSS to apply to the new content. You don't need to do anything special. You just need to not destroy the CSS (which is what `document.writeln` does when it destroys the whole page).

Comment: Thanks. How to avoid document.writeln any simple code will help me.

Comment: See the last paragraph of the answer.